# Copy Data from Search results to another items from block in Oracle Forms Builder

Tags: forms, oracle

Okay, I'm not sure if I can explain this well.

This is what it looks like at runtime:

[image: output at runtime]

The list of display items from above are the data that came from database query.
I put a 'When mouse click' trigger to every row so that when I click a row, it copies all the data to the field below. It works when I first try to click a row but when I click another row which supposed to change the data below, NOTHING HAPPENS anymore.

here is my canvas' variable names:

[image]

here is what's inside of the 'When mouse click' trigger:

[image]

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This tiny line of code did the trick.

`GO_ITEM(SYSTEM.MOUSE_RECORD);`

it simply tells what row number the item you clicked inside the record is in. It gives a char value of zero '0' when you clicked an item outside the record.

For more uses of the SYSTEM variables, check this very useful link. Thanks!

http://oraclet.blogspot.com/2008/02/system-variables-toutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse click code is not working because when you are clicking on search block then currently you are in that block so you should have to move to FLIGHT block before assigning the values also you have to move to next record to populate the values into new record otherwise it will rewrite the values on existing, below is the example given for your problem:

on mouse click add these lines before your code

```
Begin
    Go_Block('flight');
    loop
       if flight.flight_id is null then
          -- look for the empty record if found then exit and assign values
          exit;
       end if;
       -- else continue finding empty record
       next_record;
    end loop;
end;
```

--- paste your mouse click trigger code below